# Versioning system with Lock-Modify-Unlock

Tags: version-control, versioning

I'm looking at a case of version control where the only data is one big non readable file. As it is not readable without a special tool any merging conflicts of this file would be a big hassle.

My idea to handle this is to use a version control Lock-Modify-Unlock model. Does anyone know of a system implementing this?

Does any one have a better idea then to use this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For up-to-date VCS you can have lock-unlock model only in [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html)

Answer (score -2):

In the past I worked with MS VSS, which prevented other users from working on a file once I started working on it.
Pretty sure other versioning platforms implement this as well.